# TYPO3 Fluid: f:image trim image then scale

Tags: typo3, fluid

I have a square image of 1200x1200px. Now I want to cut off / trim all sides by 80px and then scale it down to 275px. How is this possible?

```
<f:image src="path/to/image.jpg" width="275c" />
```

This just scales down the image, so I took a look at the [imgResource Core Documentation](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.1.0/view/5/2/) that told me, you can crop images by substracting x percent.

```
<f:image src="path/to/image.jpg" width="1120c-93" height="1120c-93" />
```

93% of 1200px are roughly 1120px.

Next try was to first crop, then scale, but it seems that I'm not able to trim a square image at all.

```
<f:image src="{f:uri.image(src: 'path/to/image.jpg', width: '1200c-93')}" width="275" />
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how to solve the problem?

**Edit**

So I tried the following with fixed width and height:

```
<f:image src="{f:uri.image(src: '{item.imagePath}image_001.jpg', width: '1120c-50', height: '1120c-50')}" width="275" height="275" alt="{item.name}" />
<f:image src="{item.imagePath}image_001.jpg" alt="{item.name}" width="275" alt="{item.name}" />
```

But this gives me two identical images: http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/204/nsuo.png

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify an explicit `height` in the inner call and the crop values must be smaller than the original image size. So try this one:

```
<f:image src="{f:uri.image(src: 'path/to/image.jpg', width: '1120c-93', height: '1120c-93')}" width="275" alt="" />
```

Comment: Can you try to leave out the `-50` in the dimension attributes? I've tried it with an example image in my 4.7 installation and it worked as expected (I left out the `-93` in my try). Which TYPO3 version do you use?

Comment: What a shame, it seems like such an easy task... I use T3 6.1.1 and I also tried it with 4.7.11, however I always get a down-scaled image. With or without `c`, a negative or positive number after `c` and `maxWidth`, `maxHeight`, `width` or `height`. I tried every possible combination, I guess. :(

Comment: I also tried it with a Typoscript solution and embedded it as `<f:cObject />`, but it didn't worked, too.

Comment: Obviously it works fine when the dimension ratio is changed. If I use 100/200 for width/height it gets cropped, if the ratio stays the same, it is only scaled down. This is also described in the docs (http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.1.0/view/5/2/). => The image is FIRST scaled down preserving the proportions and THEN cropped if necessary.

Comment: The essential thing is, " the crop values must be smaller than the original image size" If The image is smaller and has to be scaled up, it doesn't work yet